# Cannot get rawr to build jar from a very simple JRuby script

Tags: ruby, jar, jruby

I'm having problems getting rawr to build a jar file. I'm using JRuby 1.6.5.1 on OS X Lion.

Installation:

```
jruby --1.9 -S rawr install
```

In the src directory I create a simple hello_jruby.rb containing:

```
puts "Hello JRuby!"
```

The build_configuration.rb file has the following settings:

```
c.project_name = "hello_jruby"
c.executable_type = "console"
c.main_ruby_file = "hello_jruby"
```

Generate the jar file:

```
$ jruby --1.9 -S rake rawr:jar
mkdir -p package/classes/java
javac -target 1.6 -cp lib/java/jruby-complete.jar:src -sourcepath src -d package/classes/java src/org/monkeybars/rawr/Main.java
mkdir -p package/classes/ruby
Copying source file src/hello_jruby.rb to package/classes/ruby/hello_jruby.rb
cp src/hello_jruby.rb package/classes/ruby/hello_jruby.rb
mkdir -p package/classes/META-INF
mkdir -p package/jar
=== Creating jar file: package/jar/hello_jruby.jar
cp lib/java/jruby-complete.jar package/jar/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar
```

Neither execution of the jar file prints the output:

```
$ java -jar ./hello_jruby.jar 

$ java -cp .:./lib/java/jruby-complete.jar -jar ./hello_jruby.jar
```

I'm totally confused as to why this doesn't work. I have tried on Windows, but the CLASSPATH separator used by rawr is a colon(:) instead of a semi-colon(;) so the rawr:jar doesn't work.

I must be missing something or don't fully understand how to use rawr.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Additional Attempts and Results

Installed the latest JRuby (not using RVM):

```
$ jruby --1.9 -v
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_33) [darwin-x86_64-java]
```

Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

Installed the latest rawr:

```
$ jruby --1.9 -S gem install rawr --source http://gems.neurogami.com
Fetching: rawr-1.6.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rawr-1.6.3
1 gem installed
```

One thing I noticed is that the rawr executable is placed in the Ruby 1.9.2 directory. Is this normal and expected?

```
$ which rawr
/Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rawr
```

The following command fails now. I previously had installed JRuby using RVM. Prior to installing the latest JRuby I uninstalled the RVM JRuby.

```
$ jruby --1.9 -S rake -T
(in /Users/david/Dropbox/SourceCode/Ruby/RubySandbox/rawr_test)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ftools

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

However, running rake via ruby 1.9.2 works:

```
$ rake -T
```

Generated the jar using the following:

```
$ rake rawr:jar
```

Still getting no output or errors when generating the jar.

```
$ java -jar ./hello_jruby.jar 
$
```

Running the script using JRuby is successful:

```
$ jruby --1.9 ./hello_jruby.rb 
Hello JRuby!
```

The generated jar has the following files:

```
$ ls -R
META-INF        java            ruby
hello_jruby.rb      org         run_configuration

./META-INF:
MANIFEST.MF

./java:

./org:
monkeybars

./org/monkeybars:
rawr

./org/monkeybars/rawr:
Main.class

./ruby:
```

TEST01: Using system JRuby and avoiding RVM Ruby 1.9.2.

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2

$ gem uninstall rawr

$ rvm system

$ jruby --1.9 -S gem install rawr --source http://gems.neurogami.com

$ which rawr
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin/rawr

$ jruby --1.9 -S rawr install

$ jruby --1.9 -S rake rawr:jar
```

The rawr executable is now in a different location. However, still getting no output from the jar. I even tried all jruby commands without --1.9 with no difference. I'm going to give it a another shot on Windows too.

Next test is to pull the latest rawr source and run through the mentioned instructions.

Thanks again!

Comment: What actually happens when you try to run the jar? Also, how did you install rawr? If it was from `gem install rawr`, it's probably pretty old; get it from https://github.com/rawr/rawr for the newest. You might also want to update JRuby at least to 1.6.7.

Comment: EDIT: Or use `gem install rawr --source http://gems.neurogami.com`.

Comment: The command prompt returns with no output or errors. I will install the gem pointing to the source and see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: `$ jruby --1.9 -S gem install rawr --source http://gems.neurogami.com
Successfully installed rawr-1.6.3
1 gem installed`

Comment: Still no luck. No output or errors. Will try updating JRuby.

Comment: Latest JRuby didn't help. See main post with updated information and results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: no, the gem probably shouldn't show up under your 1.9.2 install. RVM must think you're still using 1.9.2. Since your JRuby is outside of rvm, type `rvm system` to ignore all rvm-installed Rubys. You might want to uninstall rawr from 1.9.2 first.

(An aside: I just installed rawr under my 1.9.3 Ruby and it still worked fine. Weird.)

Following up on my comments: I've done some digging and it looks like the gem hosted at neurogami.com is still behind git HEAD. I got that same error about ftools using it. What I have done to get it working (on Ubuntu and Windows) is:

1. `gem install bones`
2. `gem install rspec -v 1.3.0`
3. `git clone https://github.com/rawr/rawr.git`
4. `cd rawr`
5. `rake gem:package`
6. `gem install pkg/rawr-1.6.3.gem`
7. `cd ..`
8. `mkdir rawr-test-TEMP`
9. `cd rawr-test-TEMP`
10. `rawr install`
11. create hello_jruby.rb and add proper config options to build_configuration.rb (I also had to add `c.target_jvm_version = 1.7` because rawr didn't pick up my Java 7 install)
12. edit line 667 of lib/zip/zip.rb inside your rawr gem's directory -- add a closing parenthesis to the end. This is a bug in upstream rawr.
13. `rake rawr:jar`

Comment: Oh, instead of editing zip.rb in step 12, you can edit it in the rawr source directory between steps 4 and 5. It's in ./lib/zip/zip.rb.

Comment: Great thanks. I'm going to give that a try. Using rvm system didn't work for me. I'm also going to give Windows a shot again.

Comment: Still no joy from the Mac, but Windows is working with the simple hello_jruby.rb. I updated Windows to JRuby 1.6.7.2 and installed the http://gems.neurogami.com rawr gem. For now, I'll work on the Windows side. If you really want to troubleshoot the mac side we can revert to email and report back here?

Comment: I found the problem. In the build_configuration.rb file if the c.project_name is set to the same name as the source file, in this case "hello_jruby", it fails to output. Windows and Mac work fine with a different project_name.

Comment: Now, that we got it working, do you know if there's an easy code change to force it to use --1.9 mode within the built .jar? It seems it defaults to 1.8 mode according to the following thread. http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4114350

Comment: I spent a while today on this and couldn't find *any* change to make it use 1.9 mode. I tried passing `-Djruby.compat.version=RUBY1_9` to java, but then the program just ended without producing any output. I brought this up on the rawr list, so hopefully it gets addressed.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your time and effort. For now I will work around the 1.9 features.